# Example(s) of topological fields that are not locally compact

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, topological-groups

It seems to me that most topological fields studied in mathematics are locally compact, e.g. local fields in number theory.

Are there examples of topological fields that are not locally compact? Do they arise naturally?

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Any (complete or not) infinite extension of a local field is not locally compact. This includes the algebraic closure or the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. Perfectoid fields are another host of natural examples.